# Direct proof that Brody hyperbolic implies algebraically hyperbolic

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, kobayashi-hyperbolicity

**Setup.** Let $X$ be a compact complex manifold. Let $\sum\limits \omega_{jk}d{z_j}\otimes d\overline{z}_k$ be a Hermitian metric on $X$ with associated positive $(1,1)$-form $\omega = \frac{i}{2}\sum \omega_{jk}d{z_j}\wedge d\overline{z}_k$.

Recall that $X$ is *Brody hyperbolic* if there is no non-constant holomorphic map $\mathbb{C}\to X$ and that $X$ is *Kobayashi hyperbolic* if the Kobayashi pseudo-metric on $X$ is a genuine metric.
By work of Kobayashi and Brody, it is known that these two conditions are equivalent since we assume that $X$ is compact.

In Theorem 2.1 of [here](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/%7Edemailly/manuscripts/hyperbolic.pdf), Demailly proved that $X$ being Kobayashi hyperbolic (equivalently $X$ being Brody hyperbolic) implies that $X$ is algebraically hyperbolic (i.e., there exists a positive constant $c$ such that the degree of any curve of genus $g$ on $X$, where the degree of $C$ is given by $\text{deg}_{\omega}(C) = \int_{C}\omega$ for $\omega$ defined above, is bounded from above by $c(g-1)$). His proof crucially uses properties of the Kobayashi metric and the Gauss--Bonnet theorem.

**Question.** Is there a direct proof of the fact that $X$ being Brody hyperbolic implies that $X$ is algebraically hyperbolic? By a direct proof, I mean one which does **not** use any properties of the Kobayashi metric and only uses the non-existence of entire curves in $X$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a motivation to expect (or hope) such a proof to exist?

Comment: @WillSawin I don’t have any motivation to expect such a proof to exist. The hope for such a proof comes from results in non-Archimedean hyperbolicity which describe how one can inherit a non-Archimedean analogue of Brody hyperbolicity from hyperbolicity of the special fiber. I hope there is a proof that Brody implies algebraically hyperbolic so that I could try to adapt that to the non-Archimedean setting.

Comment: What is the degree of a curve in a compact complex manifold?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Thanks for the comment! I just edited the question to define what I meant by degree.